# 'Public Shared Sub Main()' has multiple definitions with identical signatures." in Visual Studio while running windows service

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, windows-services

Main sub gives error:

> 'Public Shared Sub Main()' has multiple definitions with identical signatures.

Nowhere I can use usage of main sub.

```vb
Imports System.ServiceProcess

Public Class MetricArchiver
    Inherits System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase

    Public WithEvents Arc As Archiver
    Public WithEvents Timer1 As System.Timers.Timer

    Public Sub New()

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
        Timer1 = New System.Timers.Timer
        Timer1.Interval = 30000
        Timer1.Enabled = False
    End Sub

    Public Shared Sub Main() << This gives error. 
        System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.Run(New MetricArchiver)
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnStart(ByVal args() As String)
        Arc = New Archiver()
        Arc.Run()
        Timer1.Enabled = True
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnStop()
        Arc.Halt()
        Timer1.Enabled = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Elapsed(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs) Handles Timer1.Elapsed

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Have you looked for the other `Public Shared Sub Main()`?

Comment: Yes, I don't see any. That's strange to me.

Comment: You've checked all files in the project?

Comment: Yes that's the only file in which I am using this class.
In designed.vb class, this is what I am seeeing:
' The main entry point for the process
    <MTAThread()> _
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode()> _
    Shared Sub Main()
        Dim ServicesToRun() As System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase

        ' More than one NT Service may run within the same process. To add
        ' another service to this process, change the following line to
        ' create a second service object. For example,
        '

Comment: '   ServicesToRun = New System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase () {New Service1, New MySecondUserService}
        '
        ServicesToRun = New System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase() {New MetricArchiver}

        System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun)
    End Sub

Comment: Merge above 2 comments

Comment: If you comment out your `Main`, does it work? Did you change the project's "Application" tab -> "Startup object" dropdown in "Project" menu -> "<yourprojectname> Properties..."?

Comment: If i comment Main, and then try to start the service, it gives me error message: "The "service name" service on Local Computer started and then stopped. Some services stop automatically if they are not in use by other service or programs"

Comment: @user3857963 Did you change the project's "Application" tab -> "Startup object" dropdown in "Project" menu -> "<yourprojectname> Properties..."? Just to make sure, I created a new Windows service which instantiates a Threading.Timer in the OnStart method. The timer's callback handler runs on time. There is no New method or Main needed. I left the aforementioned property set to the default of "Service1".

Comment: My guess is that because your `Main` sub is declared as a shared sub that it is conflicting with `New`. What does your implementation look like?